# Compare columns in MS Excel

Tags: excel

Following is a sample excel spreadsheet. The requirement is to compare each column (say B) with column C and count the number of rows in which both B and C have numbers. For instance, both B and C have values in the first and second rows but only B has a value in the third row, so the output should be 2.

I tried to use if condition in the following manner:

```
if(and(isnumber(b2),isnumber(c2)),1,0)
```

but it works only for one row not all rows.

How do I achieve this result in MS Excel?

```
╔═══╦════════╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
║   ║   A    ║ B ║ C ║ D ║ E ║ F ║
╠═══╬════════╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
║ 1 ║        ║ 4 ║ 5 ║   ║ 6 ║ 5 ║
║ 2 ║        ║ 2 ║ 5 ║   ║ 2 ║   ║
║ 3 ║        ║ 1 ║   ║ 2 ║ 6 ║ 7 ║
║ 4 ║        ║   ║   ║   ║   ║   ║
║ 5 ║ Output ║ 2 ║   ║ 0 ║ 2 ║ 1 ║
╚═══╩════════╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
```

Answer (score 1):

Place this formula where ever you want to see the results

```
=COUNTIFS(B1:B4,"<>",C1:C4,"<>")
```

The `"<>"` only counts non-blank cells, but it will count `#NAME?` ,`#DIV/0`, and `#REF`

This can be avoided **if zero is also not an acceptable value** by adding two more criteria

```
=COUNTIFS(B1:B4,"<>",C1:C4,"<>",B1:B4,">0",C1:C4,">0"!)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to compare all column combinations then you can use `SUMPRODUCT`:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT($A6&"$1:"&$A6&"$3"))),--(ISNUMBER(B$1:B$3)))`

[image]

See [this link](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/11/10/excel-sumproduct-formula/) for explanation of "Using SUMPRODUCT as an array formula".